# Potential job as IT Specialist/Sharepoint Developer.. have some questions!

Tags: development, asp.net, jobs

Okay, so here's the deal:

I have lots of self-taught experience with web development, with one pretty successful website built on PHP/MySql with a front end of Html, Css, Javascript, and the Jquery Library.  Recently, I've also ported that site into an Android app through Phonegap.  I have little to no experience with C#, ASP, VB, or Sharepoint.

Other than my web development experience, I have 4 years experience working in one of the Navy's data centers monitoring their networks and servers (Cisco network with Windows 2003 IIS/SMTP/HTTPS/MSSQL, and some Redhat Linux machines) along with providing "customer" support to the fleet.

After applying for a networking position, I was told they aren't currently hiring in the network department but providing me with information on this SharePoint developer position.  Like I said, I have no experience with SP or ASP, but I also don't have a firm grasp on what exactly SP Developing is.  My phone interview is with a close family friend, whose the department head and would be my boss.  Because of that, It's likely I have a good chance at this position, assuming they are okay with my lack of specific knowledge.  Is this something I have a reasonable chance at or am I going to be to far behind the curve to get any work done?  Any tips or advice would be appreciated!

Thanks guys, sorry for the novel.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to be hurting for a while if you take this position. SharePoint has too many fkced up intricacies to be able to just pick it up on the fly while developing. You will pick it up relatively quickly though with your existing knowledge, so you may be able to fake it until you make it depending on what they expect out of you initially.

Comment: That's more or less what I assumed, thanks for confirming. I imagine it's going to be like learning PHP.. Horrible to learn, not bad once you get the hang of the complete lack of logic and naming conventions.  I plan to be upfront about my lack of experience with it all, I know the guy too well to lie about it.  Thanks for the response!